# WPF Entity Framework refresh one context entity

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, catel

I have a simple MVVM WPF app with database-first EF dbContext (which is `Global.Database` in my app), which is long-living in my application.
I have a window with a listbox with `ItemsSource` binded to viewmodel property called `Clients` which is an `ObservableCollection` of my dbmodel `Client`.

The `SelectedItem` of this listbox is binded to a viewmodel property called `SelectedClient`.

In `Client` entity class there is a field called `last_status` which is a simple int from my database.

So, in my view, when i select client from listbox, a label binded to SelectedClient's `last_status` should show the value of `last_status`.

I added a button and a refresh command into my viewmodel. All i want is: when i manually change `last_status` for the client in my database and press refresh button in my view, the content of label should change. But i have absolutely no idea how to achieve this. Here is the part of my viewmodel code (i use Catel, but it doesn't matter for this case):

```
public ClientManagerWindowViewModel()
    {

       RefreshClientInfoCommand = new Command(OnRefreshClientInfoCommandExecute);

       Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
       RefreshClients();
    }

public ObservableCollection<Client> Clients
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<Client>>(ClientsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClientsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData ClientsProperty = RegisterProperty("Clients", typeof(ObservableCollection<Client>));

public Client SelectedClient
    {
        get
        {return GetValue<Client>(SelectedClientProperty);}
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedClientProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData SelectedClientProperty = RegisterProperty("SelectedClient", typeof(Client));


//here is my refresh button command handler:

 public Command RefreshClientInfoCommand { get; private set; }

 private void OnRefreshClientInfoCommandExecute()
 {
     RefreshClientInfo(SelectedClient);
 }

//and here is my "logic" for working with dbcontext:

private void RefreshClients()
    {
        var qry = (from c in Global.Database.Clients where c.client_id != 1 select c).ToList();
        Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>(qry);
    }

private void RefreshClientInfo(Client client)
    {
        Global.Database.Entry(client).Reload();
    }
```

My XAML for a listbox:

```
<ListBox
                    x:Name="ClientsListBox"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="5"
                    DisplayMemberPath="fullDomainName"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient}" />
```

My XAML for a label:

```
<Label Margin="5" Content="{Binding SelectedClient.last_status}" />
```

And for a button:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RefreshClientInfoCommand}" Content="↻"/>
```

For now, when i change a client's `last_status` value manually in database and press refresh button nothing happens. But when i select another client in a listbox and then return to needed client - label content updates correctly. I know, maybe i miss something very stupid and simple, but i cant' figure out what exactly. Maybe i need to force change `SelectedClient` in my button command handler, or call `SelectedClient`s setter somehow...
Please, help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should refresh the binding too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i figured out what was wrong with my code.

My databindig was set to `SelectedClient.last_status`. For some reason it didn't work as i expected. So i created a new viewmodel property called LastStatus and modified my RefreshClientInfo:

```
 private void RefreshClientInfo(Client client)
    {
        Global.Database.Entry(client).Reload();
        LastStatus = client.last_status;
        SetValue(SelectedClientProperty, client);
    }
```

and binded label to this new property. Now everything works correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `SelectedClient` property to the new `Client` object that you get back from the EF query.

You could do this by storing the `client_id` of the currently selected client before you query the database and then select the new `Client` object with this particular `client_id`.

Try this:

```
private void RefreshClients()
{
    int? currentlySelectedClientId = (SelectedClient != null) ? SelectedClient.client_id : default(int?);
    var qry = (from c in Global.Database.Clients where c.client_id != 1 select c).ToList();
    Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>(qry);
    if (currentlySelectedClientId.HasValue)
        SelectedClient = Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.client_id = currentlySelectedClientId.Value);
}
```

**Edit:** Make sure that you fetch the updated records from the DB:

```
private void RefreshClientInfo(Client client)
{
    var newClient = (from c in Global.Database.Clients where c.client_id == client.client_id select c).ToList();
    SetValue(SelectedClientProperty, newClient[0]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i can't see how it may help me  - i don't want to refresh all clients, i want to refresh only one. and the function i'm generally asking for is `RefreshClientInfo(Client client)`, not `RefreshClients()`. But maybe i don't understand something.

Comment: You need to re-fetch the client from the database after you have updated it. See my edit.

Comment: still not refreshing when i press the button :( It refreshes when i change selected client in listbox and return back.

Comment: You need to make sure that you fetch the updated item from the database and you are setting the property and raise the PropertyChanged event for it. See my edit.

Comment: well, now it stopped working at all and not refreshing nether by button, nor by selecting another client and returning back, when i commented out `Global.Database.Entry(client).Reload` and put your code from Edit.

Comment: Why are you calling the RefreshClientInfo method in setter of the property?

Comment: removed it from setter. still nothing refreshes when use your code:(

Comment: Read this and update your question accordingly then: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve